# Stripe - Flutter: Missing required param: type

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate payment using a Card in one of the mobile application using Flutter. I am following this tutorial.

[Flutter app using Stripe and Firebase](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-marketplace-in-your-flutter-app-and-accept-payments-using-stripe-and-firebase-72f3f7228625)

I am getting the following error in the cloud function. "Missing required param: type." Even I included the type in cloud function like this.

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: req.query.amount,
      currency: req.query.currency,
      confirmation_method: 'automatic',
      type: 'standard',
      payment_method: clonedPaymentMethod.id,
      stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount,
      confirm: true,
    });
```

Anyone can guide me? Thanks.

Comment: `type` is not a parameter you can pass in when creating a Payment Intent. Is it possible the error is coming from somewhere else in your code?

Comment: But this error is coming from Stripe API.

Comment: Yes it's coming from Stripe, but is it possible that you're making a different request to stripe before or after this?